# Why does function return only one value when called multiple times in a single printf?

Tags: c, function, printf

I ran across an issue where a function that returns a character string returns incorrect values when called multiple times within a single printf . At first I thought it was due to the static designation of binstr preventing the variable from updating. After reviewing [**How to reset static variables within a function**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488609/how-to-reset-static-variables-within-a-function) I don't think that explains the behavior. In creating the function, my goal was to avoid global variables and to avoid dynamically allocating within the function and turning over the responsibility to free() the memory to the calling routine. Below the original function `binstr_8` is listed first. For reasons I'm trying to understand if it is called multiple times within `printf` it always returns the value of the first return - but behaves as desired in all other situations (when not called multiple times in the same `printf`)

```
/* binstr_8 - binary string for uint8_t (char) */
char *
binstr_8 (uint8_t x)
{
    static char binstr [sizeof(uint8_t) * CHAR_BIT + 1] = {0};
    size_t szstr = sizeof (uint8_t) * CHAR_BIT;
    size_t z = 0;

    for (z = 0; z < szstr; z++)
        binstr [szstr - 1 - z] = ((x >> z) & 0x1) ? '1' : '0';

    return binstr;
}
```

A short example helps explain:

```
printf ("\nTesting binstr_8 & binstr_8_dyn\n\n");

be = 0b01011000;  // 88
printf (" 88 & 87 = %d  (%s)\n\n", (88 & 87), binstr_8 (88 & 87));

printf (" %d  %s  rightmost bit off: %s\n\n", be, binstr_8 (be), binstr_8 (be & (be - 1)));
printf (" 88  %s\n 87  %s\n  &  ---------\n     %s\n\n",
        binstr_8 (88), binstr_8 (87), binstr_8 (88 & 87));
```

You can download the source of the example program [**binstr_8_test.c**](http://www.3111skyline.com/dl/dev/prg/src/binstr_8_test.c) The output from the `printf` statements are:

```
Testing binstr_8 & binstr_8_dyn

88 & 87 = 80  (01010000)

88  01011000  rightmost bit off: 01011000

88  01011000
87  01011000
&  ---------
    01011000
```

When called in the `printf` line with "rightmost bit off", **each instance of `binstr_8` returns the same value: `01011000` (which is just 88, the same returned by the first call of `binstr_8` in the statement)** In fact, when `binstr_8` appears more than once in a `printf`, every call returns 88?  (I even hardcoded the values) What is going on there?

Breaking the statements up such that each `printf` contains only a single call to `binstr_8` **works**:

```
printf (" %d  %s  rightmost bit off: ", be, binstr_8 (be));
printf ("%s\n\n", binstr_8 (be & (be - 1)));
printf (" 88  %s\n", binstr_8 (88));
printf (" 87  %s\n", binstr_8 (87));
printf ("  &  ---------\n     %s\n\n", binstr_8 (88 & 87));
```

Output:

```
88  01011000  rightmost bit off: 01010000

88  01011000
87  01010111
&  ---------
    01010000
```

I can re-write the function as `binstr_8_dyn` to dynamically allocate `char *binstr` and then use the same `printf` statements containing multiple calls to the function and it **works**. **How is that possible?** Example:

```
/* same function re-written to dynamically allocate binstr */
char *
binstr_8_dyn (uint8_t x)
{
    char *binstr = NULL;
    size_t z;
    size_t szstr = sizeof (uint8_t) * CHAR_BIT;

    binstr = (char *)malloc (szstr + 1);
    binstr [szstr] = '\0';

    for (z = 0; z < szstr; z++)
        binstr [szstr - 1 - z] = ((x >> z) & 0x1) ? '1' : '0';

    return binstr;
}
/* snip */

printf (" %d  %s  rightmost bit off: %s\n\n", be, binstr_8_dyn (be), binstr_8_dyn (be & (be - 1)));
printf (" 88  %s\n 87  %s\n  &  ---------\n     %s\n\n",
        binstr_8_dyn (88), binstr_8_dyn (87), binstr_8_dyn (88 & 87));
```

The output is correct:

```
88  01011000  rightmost bit off: 01010000

88  01011000
87  01010111
&  ---------
    01010000
```

Now I have managed to totally confuse myself as to why `binstr_8` cannot be called multiple times in the same `printf` while `binstr_8_dyn` can. What fundamental principle am I overlooking? Also, how else would I provide the return without involving a global or passing a pointer other than using static or allocating dynamically?

Comment: `printf (... binstr_8 (be), binstr_8 (be & (be - 1)));` fails.  `binstr_8()` is called multiple times and changes the data in its static buffer _before_ `printf()` is ever called.  Break the `printf()` into smaller pieces.

Comment: Just to make clear: Please don't use `binstr_8_dyn()` in production code - i will leak memory. A little bit on every call, but that summates.

Comment: Yes, I know that. My goal was to avoid placing the free() burden on the caller and that is what originally drove the decision to use the static type in binstr_8. Basically, I have kept both prototypes for my binary library. binstr_8 for general use where the return pointing to a common buffer is not an issue, and binstr_8_dyn for limited use where it is. Yes, I know both issues could be solved by passing a pointer to store the return, but that was something else I was trying to avoid to prevent frustrating use in printf ("%s\n", binstr_8 (var)) situations. (all solutions are ugly here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `binstr_8` function returns the same pointer every time - a pointer to your static buffer.

So if you pass it twice as argument to printf, printf receives the same buffer twice, therefore the same thing prints twice.  Both calls to `binstr_8` run before `printf` is called (a function's arguments must be evaluated before the function is called, obviously).

The `malloc` example returns a different buffer each time.

**Update**: example of using multiple static buffers, inside the `binstr_8` function:

```
static char binstr [5][CHAR_BIT + 1];
static char which = 0;
if ( ++which == 5 ) which = 0;

// use binstr[which] where you had binstr
```

Then you can use up to five calls to `binstr_8` in each `printf`.

Comment: OK, that makes sense and also explains why making `binstr` a global with `char binst[CHAR_BIT + 1]` also fails -- the multiple calls within `printf` still point to the same buffer. Then in this example, the only way for a function call to work is to dynamically allocate within the function. That's a bummer, so somehow the caller will have to manage freeing the memory.

Comment: Yeah, or you could use multiple static buffers (which is kind of ugly but all solutions are ugly here).

Comment: added an example of multiple static buffers. Note, sizeof(uint8_t) is `1` by definition although you can keep it for clarity if you think it adds to the clarity :)

Answer (score 4):

As you return the address of a `static` variable which you reuse and reuse again, the value is always the same, and it is the last one which has been calculated.

Comment: And the order of calls is also unspecified.

Comment: That was another piece of the puzzle. So basically it was a dice-roll which answer I would get depending on the order in which the multiple `binstr_8`'s were evaluated -- which was indeterminable to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a pointer to the static buffer so all of the binstrs point to the *same* memory location. When you create a new one you are overwriting all of the existing binstrs. With binstr_dyn they are are different buffers. As all of your arguments are evaluated before the function call the printf prints the values of the last string created, which happens to be 88 because to order of evaluation of arguments is undefined.

binstr_8_dyn is the correct inplementation but you will neet to rember to free every string it creates.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Matt McNabb's answer:

For a function like that the output string length can be determined in advance, so you can make a caller to allocate the output buffer. Buffers can be automatic and you avoid problems with deallocation:

```
#define STR8LEN     (sizeof (uint8_t) * CHAR_BIT)
#define STR8BUFLEN  (sizeof (uint8_t) * CHAR_BIT + 1)

char *binstr_8 (uint8_t x, char *binstr)
{
    size_t z;
    size_t szstr = STR8LEN;

    binstr [szstr] = 0;
    for (z = 0; z < szstr; x >>= 1, z++)
        binstr [szstr - 1 - z] = '0' + (x & 1);

    return binstr;
}

void fun()
{
    char buf1 [STR8BUFLEN], buf2 [STR8BUFLEN], buf3 [STR8BUFLEN];

    printf (" 88  %s\n 87  %s\n  &  ---------\n     %s\n\n",
        binstr_8 (88, buf1), binstr_8 (87, buf2),
        binstr_8 (88 & 87, buf3));
}
```

It's a caller function `fun()` responsibility to allocate buffers prior to call and free them after use; `binstr_8` just uses them. Each time `binstr_8` is called with a separate buffer, so the results do not overlap, and each call returns its own buffer as a result, so they can be used by printf. You can also use them later, as they keep their contents as long as they exist (provided you do not overwrite them!):

```
void fun()
{
    char buf1 [STR8BUFLEN], buf2 [STR8BUFLEN], buf3 [STR8BUFLEN];

    binstr_8 (88, buf1);
    binstr_8 (87, buf2);
    binstr_8 (88 & 87, buf3);

    printf (" 88  %s\n 87  %s\n  &  ---------\n     %s\n\n",
        buf1, buf2, buf3);
}
```